# How to gather useful insights about Metro design

Tags: discussion, specific-question

With public availability of the Windows 8 Community Preview (aka Beta), we can now get our hands on, and interact with, Metro style desktop applications for the first time.

I'm sure that we could, as a community, gleen a lot of useful information from an in depth examination - identifying things in the preview applications that work really well, as well as things that work ... less well.

**How would you suggest I go about asking such a question?**

Why it belongs on UX ...

- Windows 8 is coming, and Metro apps are coming with it, for good or for ill.
- Metro "thinking" is already having an impact on websites and other applications
- It's too big for one person to do - details I might overlook would be noticed by someone else, things you think trivial might be considered important (and voted up) by many.
- I believe we *could* identify definitive answers that would be helpful for future developers and designers to reference

Why it might be a problem ...

- How do we avoid a parade of people proclaiming that it's a grand mistake and we should stay with the way its done by Windows 7, Mac OX X, Macintosh System 6, BE OS, OS/2 Warp, Lisa, AmigaOS etc
- How do we keep answers more to the objective end of the spectrum? I'm
- By focusing on the Win8CP, is it too localised in time?
- I'm sure there will be entire books written on Metro design, so perhaps this question would be too wide in scope?
- I know that List questions are generally frowned upon, for obvious reasons.

**Update 11 March:**
I've taken the plunge and [posted the question](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/18487/what-lessons-can-we-learn-about-metro-ux-from-windows-8). I'm eagerly anticipating the answers other people put forward.

Answer (score 1):

You should definitely do this.

- Don't worry about the problem areas. We avoid subjective answers by downvoting, post noticing, and ultimately deleting them if they don't answer your question.
- Answers should generally be objective anyway, so anything that isn't risks being removed.
- You don't have to focus on Win 8 CP since most of what is in it will be in the final version of Windows 8, so it will still be a relevant post in the future.
- You can break up your question into multiple questions to prevent it from being too wide in scope.
- Don't phrase it as a list question and it won't be a list question!

This could also be a great candidate for a blog post. This week Super User wrote [a blog post about using Metro with mouse and keyboard](http://blog.superuser.com/2012/03/09/win8-metro-review/) and while I was reading it I realised that this could be a great topic for us to talk about from an informed, expert UX point of view.